# Split file on a pattern

Tags: text-processing, split

I have a file as below.

```
***ABC***
Line1*
L*ine2*
***DEF***
Line3*
Lin*e4*
```

I need to create the 2 files `ABC` and `DEF` with the data below:

ABC.dat:

```
Line1*
L*ine2*
```

DEF.dat:

```
Line3*
Lin*e4*
```

I am ok to generate the file using small shell script as well.

Comment: I removed the `*` you were using since they were confusing the formatting. Are the `*` part of the file? How can we know which lines are the headers (the file names) and which the content? I mean, what's the difference between `ABC` and `Line1`? Is it every 3rd line? Is it lines with ALL CAPS? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: * is part of file. Each data line has final selimiter as *. Not every 3rd line. There will be indefinite number of lines between each pattern

Comment: OK, next time, please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your examples as code. So, can we assume that lines starting with `***` will be the target file name?

Comment: Yes correct.... target file name will be the line starting with ***

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/^\*\*\*/{gsub(/\*/,""); fname=$0".dat"; next} {print > fname}' ip.txt 
$ cat ABC.dat 
Line1*
L*ine2*
$ cat DEF.dat 
Line3*
Lin*e4*
```

- `/^\*\*\*/` match lines starting with `***`

  - `gsub(/\*/,"")` delete all `*` from such lines
  - `fname=$0".dat"` assign the remaining characters appended with `.dat` to `fname` variable
  - `next` move on to next line
- `print > fname` print current line content to filename saved in `fname`